# Shall I set an expiration mechanism for a dismissible info banner?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, best-practice, microinteractions, screen-real-estate

I'm adding a new data column to a table on a back office page (the interface is desktop only) and I want to highlight this new feature by displaying an info banner on top of said table that spans the whole width of the viewport.

This info banner has an "X" button on the top right corner that allows users to dismiss it after they read the message.

A colleague expressed concerns that some users won't dismiss the message and the vertical screen real estate will be lost so he suggested that we dismiss the message automatically after the user visits/refreshes the page three times.

I think this is not necessary and would create the risk that the user may refresh the page for some reason and not see the message at all. Also the user may want to leave the message visible so other users that use the same account see it.

It feels like unecessary overengineering but I would like to hear your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is an intermediate option, where the close button or the page refresh is not necessary and offers the certainty that the notification has been read.

Many applications like Netlify, Google Search Console or Github announce the new features through the notification icon `The Bell` on the top bar:

- When the icon is red it means that there are new features to be seen
- By clicking or hovering it, all the new features / notifications appear in a pop-up submenu
- They disappear once they have been completely read by clicking on `Learn more` link
- The icon turns gray

[image: netlify]

Answer (score 0):

Banners tend to be used for high-level alerts and status messages. They might be a little disconnected from a table, visually. It would seem you'd have to tell the user to scan the table and look for the new column.

Consider placing a dismissible tooltip directly on the new column:

[image: Table with tooltip on the new column]

It's tricky to find a dismissible alert pattern that can work with multiple users logging into the same account. One of the users is bound to dismiss the alert, thus hiding it from those who come after. So, you'll have to make a decision - is the new table column feature so important that you'll need to make sure that it will be difficult for users to miss it if they don't see the alert? It might require you to design the new feature in a way that makes users quickly understand that something is new and different.